# how to classify a transaction as a credit or debit by event code

Tags: paypal, transactions

i going to use /v1/reporting/transactions api. i want to know how can i classify a transaction to a credit or a debit by event code.

evnet code classify.

the event code defition https://developer.paypal.com/docs/transaction-search/transaction-event-codes/.

api url: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/#search_get.

```
    private String getTransactionType(String eventCode) {
        // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/transaction-search/transaction-event-codes/
        if (eventCode.startsWith("T02") || eventCode.startsWith("T03") || eventCode.startsWith("T08") ||
                eventCode.startsWith("T09")) {

            return DeWuConstant.TRANSACTION_DIRECTION_C;
        }

        return DeWuConstant.TRANSACTION_DIRECTION_D;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The classification available is the type of API used to process the payment.

In particular, the PayPal Checkout API can accept credit cards with a standard integration, and these transactions funded by a credit card will be indistinguishable from PayPal Checkout transactions using any other funding source -- including balance, a bank account, PayPal Credit, Pay Later, or other alternate local payment methods.

If you use the direct payment API to process credit cards (not available to China business accounts, as far as I know), there is a transaction type for that as described in the documentation you linked to. This classification might or might not include Advanced Credit and Debit Card transactions (but that's also not available in China).

---

In general, the transaction search API linked in your question is not worth integrating, for any purpose. Instead, use the response of capture API calls to record information in your own database for all future transactions. If you need information on pasttransactions, use the [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) Reports -> Activity Download to import a CSV to your database.